# How to add Brew to path, Fish on Ventura

Tags: macos, zsh, fish, macos-ventura

I've got Fish installed on Ventura (via the installer) as my default Shell. I've also installed Brew (via the installer).

I've seen instructions for how to add it to .zsh profile, but how / where do I add this to fish so that running brew from fish is pointed at correct place?

Answer (score 4):

Use `fish_add_path`. [Documentation is here.](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/fish_add_path.html)

Example: `fish_add_path /opt/homebrew/bin`